# How do I eliminate LLVM function calls and replace them with basic instructions?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, inlining

## My Problem

I am new to LLVM and C++.

I am currently creating an LLVM backend compiler and need to replace LLVM function calls with the instructions in its definition.
Is there already an existing pass that accomplishes this?

## Examples

For example, I have the following C code, compiled to LLVM IR with `clang-14 -S -emit-llvm`.

```c
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c = add(a, b);
    return c;
}
```

Then, I get a LLVM IR code below.

```
define dso_local i32 @add(i32 noundef %a, i32 noundef %b) #0 {
entry:
  %a.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %b.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %a, i32* %a.addr, align 4
  store i32 %b, i32* %b.addr, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %a.addr, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %b.addr, align 4
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, %1
  ret i32 %add
}

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %c = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  store i32 10, i32* %a, align 4
  store i32 20, i32* %b, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %b, align 4
  %call = call i32 @add(i32 noundef %0, i32 noundef %1)
  store i32 %call, i32* %c, align 4
  %2 = load i32, i32* %c, align 4
  ret i32 %2
}
```

I want to replace the function call `@add` with instructions in it's definition from the code above using `opt` command, and emit the following new code.

```
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %c = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  store i32 10, i32* %a, align 4
  store i32 20, i32* %b, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %b, align 4
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, %1
  store i32 %add, i32* %c, align 4
  %2 = load i32, i32* %c, align 4
  ret i32 %2
}
```

I searched the following sites for such a path, but could not find one suitable.
https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#loops-natural-loop-information

Comment: This optimization is called "inlining".  I don't know LLVM internal, so I don't know how you'd get LLVM to do *just* that without optimizing away debug-mode store/reload.  You might get clang to do something like that from using `__attribute__((always_inline))` in a debug build, but that might just generate LLVM-IR with the function inlined, rather than transforming two pieces of LLVM-IR, I don't know.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you very much. I did not know the term "inlining".
I had mistakenly thought that inlining was the job of the backend compiler.
The attribute `__attribute__((always_inline))` seems to work fine.

Comment: I assume the LLVM optimizer *can* do function inlining, but probably only if you let it optimize which might result in other optimizations as well.

Comment: There are several passes that do various kinds of inlining, and you generally can run them on their own (clang can run options by name IIRC). Of course they require some analysis passes.

Comment: FYI, also consider `__attribute__((flatten))` which you put on a function to make it inline all the calls it makes.